# sql query has few rows which are duplicate

Tags: mysql, sql

I want the value for users with the right ref and also users with extra value 1.
I have the following query  but its not giving unique rows ,its giving duplicate rows.How do I resolve that ? I really appreciate any help.

basically its repeating values of ref.id if tab2.user=1 which repeats 4,6 row again in the final query I dont want both but only one as ref.id=0 does not exist but I want extra=1.

```
    SELECT  * FROM 
    tab1,tab2 
    WHERE tab1.ref=tab2.ref 
    AND tab1.to_users = 1 
   OR users.extra=1;
```

Tab1

```
sno  users  ref  extra
    1     1     4     1
    2     2     5     0
    3     3     0     1
    4     1     0     1
    5     2     5     0
    6     3     0     1
```

Tab2

```
ref  ad    user
4     A      1
5     B      2
6     C      1
```

Comment: what is the desired output please?

Comment: currently I get rows with same sno repeating 2 or 3 times based on home many times user has ref.id .But I want based on ref.id to be 1 not 2 or 3 times the same no.

Comment: it would help if you provide expected table data (rows and columns)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After your last comment:

```
SELECT sno, users, tab1.ref, extra, max(ad) as ad
FROM 
    tab1,tab2 
    WHERE tab1.ref=tab2.ref 
    AND tab1.users = 1 
   OR tab1.extra=1
group by sno, users, ref, extra;
```

This will max the ad column (alternatively you can use min - all depends on your requirements)
example: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1837e/25

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use join

```
SELECT  * FROM 
tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.ref=tab2.ref 
WHERE tab1.users = 1 OR tab1.extra=1;
GROUP BY tab1.users
```

edit: added group by

Comment: this gives duplicate rows.

Comment: group by gives only 1 row.

Answer (score 0):

GROUP BY users, give below syntax a try

```
 SELECT  * FROM 
 tab1,tab2 
 WHERE tab1.ref=tab2.ref AND (tab1.users = 1 OR tab1.extra=1)
 GROUP BY users;
```

Its more common to also join tables than they way you write your syntax,

```
SELECT  * FROM 
tab1 JOIN tab2 ON tab1.ref=tab2.ref AND (tab1.users = 1 OR tab1.extra=1)
GROUP BY users;
```

Comment: group by gives only 1 row.

Comment: Yes but thats the only match of your WHERE clause, it should only show 1. Then you have to change the WHERE clause, but this doesnt show duplicates.

Comment: With the above WHERE. The ID 4 is the only one that matches. Even if you change to `WHERE tab1.ref=tab2.ref AND (tab1.extra=1)` then no result will be shown as the ref only matches on id 1,2,5. You need to add more rows or change the WHERE. But this will not give duplicates.

Comment: the OR clause somehow is not executing.I dont know why? the extra=1 part.

Comment: currently I get rows with same sno repeating 2 or 3 times based on home many times user has ref.id .But I want based on ref.id to be 1 not 2 or 3 times the same no.

Comment: try `GROUP BY tab1.ref`

Answer (score 0):

You should use parenthesis to change the priority of And and OR :

```
SELECT  * FROM 
    tab1,tab2 
    WHERE tab1.ref=tab2.ref 
    AND (tab1.to_users = 1 
   OR users.extra=1);
```

otherwise it will be run like this :

```
SELECT  * FROM 
        tab1,tab2 
        WHERE (tab1.ref=tab2.ref 
        AND tab1.to_users = 1 )
       OR users.extra=1;
```

UPDFATE:

I thought you were looking for rows with same reference where to_users is one or extra is one. Then as Krzysztof Rosiński says LEFT JOIN should do the trick but there's no need to use GROUP BY  and perhaps you should use DISTINCT something like this :

```
SELECT DISTINCT  * FROM 
tab1 LEFT JOIN tab2 ON tab1.ref=tab2.ref 
WHERE tab1.users = 1 OR tab1.extra=1;
```

Comment: the above code is not working the way it expected to.I gives only 1 row